# Angular 2 jsDoc for constructor

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, jsdoc

In my Angular class (Typescript) I have a constructor:

```
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    [...]
  }
```

Is this the correct way for jsDoc to comment the argument for this constructor?

```
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {Http} Http service
   * called when the ApiService is created
   */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can omit @constructor tag as jsDoc is capable of decuting this information by parsing your code. Check for samples here: [howto es2015 classes](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-es2015-classes.html)

As a side note.

I find useful the following utility to create documentation for the typescript projects: [TypeDoc](http://typedoc.io/)
It supports the same syntax as jsDoc and play nicely with typescript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried TypeDoc which raises another problem. It doesn't find my Angular modules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015994/typedoc-can-not-find-angular2-modules

Comment: Regarding my question I am curious how to define `@param {Http} Http service` since it is an injectable

Comment: I think this will be impossible with jsDoc at least now. As a workaround though - you are not forced into using this syntax for injectable services. You can declare public property 'http' and initialize it in constructor manually, with constructor having signature like: constructor(http: Http){this.http = http;}. This will allow you to use usual documentation tags.