# TypeDoc can not find Angular2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, typedoc

I am trying to generate doc files by using TypeDoc. When I run TypeDoc with the follwing command:

```
/node_modules/.bin/typedoc --module system --target ES5 --exclude *.spec.ts* --experimentalDecorators --out typedoc app/ --ignoreCompilerErrors
```

It gives as output:

```
Using TypeScript 1.6.2 from /development/node_modules/typedoc/node_modules/typescript/lib
Error: /development/app/angular2/app.ts(1)
 Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
Error: /development/app/angular2/app.ts(2)
 Cannot find module 'angular2/upgrade'.
Error: /development/app/angular2/app.ts(3)
 Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.
Error: /development/app/angular2/app.ts(5)
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Is there some kind of parameter I am missing here to include the libs or `.d.ts.` files?

Comment: Possibly some issue related to tsconfig.json. Can you post that?

Comment: I have added my tsconfig,json to the question

Answer (score 3):

I tried with the commonjs module and it worked.

```
typedoc --experimentalDecorators --target 'es5' --module 'commonjs' --out doc-destination/ src/
```

Answer (score 1):

I use typedoc with angular2 application. Although I run it through gulp-typedoc the passed parameters should be the same. The following gulp task does the job for me:

```
gulp.task("doc", function() {
    return gulp
        .src(["./myproject/**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(typedoc({ 
            // TypeScript options (see typescript docs) 
            module: "commonjs", 
            target: "es5",
            includeDeclarations: false,
            experimentalDecorators: true,

            // Output options (see typedoc docs) 
            out: "./docs", 

            // TypeDoc options (see typedoc docs) 
            name: "MyProject", 
            ignoreCompilerErrors: false,
            excludeExternals:true,
            version: true,
        }));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the configuration for type definition files in your tsconfig.json and try

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types" ]
```